# What's the best way to offer a free trial period for chrome extensions?

Tags: time, google-chrome-extension, payment-processing

I would like to offer a 7-day trial period for people who install my chrome extension.

After that, they would be required to input a licence key (purchased via gumroad) in order for the extension to continue to work.

I do not want to deal with registrations (emails, passwords etc.). The big risk is that the user simply uninstalls the extension when the 7-days are up, and then reinstalls it.

How do I offer the trial and avoid this scenario? Tie each install to a specific IP address perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you *do* have to deal with some sort of registration.

1. User installs app
2. Have them log in/register to start using it

There's an article about it that might help you with it, ideally using the user’s existing Google account instead of registering a new one: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/webstore/identify_user/